# execute a command if substitution succeded

Tags: sed

I would like to remove `\"` from perl script with sed,

```
 sed -ne ' 
    #(here some substitutions...)
    s/print "\(.*[^"]\)"/\1/p;
 ' | \
 sed -e 's/\\"/"/g'
```

Is it possible to only substitute `\"`  by `"` on lines where the first substitution was done?  In other word to make this script in one line?

Branching is not cool, because if a not listed previous substitution has been done, the condition is considered as true (but the latest substitution has not been done)...

EXEMPLE:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
(...)
while (@someArray) {
    print "la variable \"$_\" est cool!\n"; 
    syslog ('info|machin', "la variable \"$_\" est cool!"); 
}
```

to

```
"la variable "$_" est cool!\n"
```

but no possible substitution in

```
 syslog ('info|machin', "la variable \"$_\" est cool!");
```

If this line was previously selected.

Comment: I think that some sample input data with expected output will be very helpful for those users who wish to help you.

Comment: @MUYBelgium Please can you provide sample input and output???

Comment: from your description, if you stick with `sed (single sed)`,  `t` or `T(gnu sed)` is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -ne ' 
# if other substitution are to be made without regarding of s/print....
#(here some substitutions...) 

    s/print "\(.*[^"]\)"/\1/;
    t bs

# if other substitution are to be made if /print... is NOT found
#(here some substitutions...) 
    b

: bs
# if other substitution are to be made if /print... is found
#(here some substitutions...) 
    s/\\"/"/g
    p
'
```

after a `s//`, there is the `t` that mean Test and goto label (`bs` in this case) if true.

So here, substitute, if occuring, go to `bs` and make other substitution than print the result, if not true, go to the end (`b` without label following)

(code review due to different interpretation about other substitution)

Comment: The bs branch is taken even if a previous substitution occurred.  Not only the latest.

Comment: s/print.... occur than test on it, going to bs if substitution was made, if not it goes to b(ranch) that goes to end of actions. A test is from last substitution (apply or not) so test is after a s//

Comment: :-) interpration may change the result about "other substition". I adapt the code in consequence